# How to change active record column type from boolean to integer without db:migrate?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean, dbmigrate

I have a model like this:

```
  create_table :settings do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.boolean :send_notification, :default => true
  end
```

It was running well until I need to specify multiple types of notification (email and/or sms) and I want the user to be able to specify which notification that he needs. So I thought it was doable when I look at my settting table in database:

```
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id              | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| send_notification    | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So I was thinking to reuse send_notification column with bit-masking, e.g. 0 means nothing, 1 means email only, 2 means sms only, and 3 means both sms and email. It was all working well in database, but when I tried it in script/console. I realized that it's not possible to do so (bit-masking on boolean field).

```
ree > setting = Setting.first
 => #<Setting id: 1, user_id: 1, send_notification: false> 
ree > setting.send_notification = 2
 => 2 
ree > setting
 => #<Setting id: 1, user_id: 1, send_notification: false>
```

So I need to alter the column type, but it's a bit costly as my table is very big. Is there any better solution other than creating migration file and `rake db:migrating`?

Answer (score 1):

Boolean data type is represented as TINYINT(1), so it is a byte. If the field `send_notification` was used as bool, there should be '0' - false, '1' - 'true' or NULL values. If there are valuse > 1, they can be changed with '1' -

```
UPDATE settings SET send_notification = 1 WHERE send_notification > 1;
```

Now, you can use this field for your flags (NULL, 0, 1, 2...). If you want, you can alter table to change TINYINT to other integer type.

Also, MySQL has useful [BIT functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-functions.html).